# Identify the custom controls i have used in an xpage

Tags: xpages

I have a tricky question. I have a label control that uses a custom property called "Identifier" where i put unique keys for each control i am using. I have reused the control quit alot in my xpage.

Now i want to create some configurations based on all the values i have used in the Identifier property.

As i dont want to go to my xpage again and try to find all the custom properties i would like to write a xpage that gives me a list of all the identifier i have put into the design so that i can use it in a drop down box.

I tried to read the xpage with DXL but the design is stored in a raw format and not in text(thank you IBM).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use menu "Search / File..." in Designer to find all custom controls with "identifier"?

Comment: Why do you want that dropdown? I wonder...

Comment: The user updating the configuration doesnt have designer access. If one of the identifier is missing he doesnt even know. Thats why a dropdown with all possible identifier is necessary. I need that functionality for multilanguage support and custom labeling.

Comment: If the user has no designer access, even s/he modifies design, it will not compile. I suggest using resource bundles or application scope beans for multilingual support.